# WARN:Authentication error: ntlm authorization challenge expected, but not found in Soap UI

Tags: wcf, soapui

I am trying to access WCF Webservice using Windows Authentication in Soap UI.

I am getting 401 unauthorized.

Following are the set up I done.

1. In Request Authorization Tab, I have given as `NTLM`
2. I have given username, password and Domain.

As well as WSS-Password Type: `PasswordText` or `PasswordDigest`, and `Wss-TimeToLive`: 2000

Tried for Basic and Kerberos as well. Getting 401 response ONLY..

Getting following in the http log.

> WARN:Authentication error: ntlm authorization challenge expected, but not found

What needs to be done to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are connecting to a VPN in order to access the webservice, and that you have already verified the credentials are correct (ie: by accessing the endpoint in a browser). I will also assume your soapUI's ntlm configuration is correct.

If so, add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to your .vmoptions file (under `bin` directory).